# How to use other classes object in .phtml file without object manager in magento 2

Tags: object, magento2

I am  currently invoking the method “xyz” using the object manager, however the object manager should not be used in phtml file  as mentioned in the Magento 2 documentation. What is the best practice  to create an object of other classes in phtml file?

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

***ViewModel*** files can be used to add codes in a template file without using an object manager.

Here Are Steps to create View Model

Step 1:- Create a layout file in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/custom_index_custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block name="dummy" template="Sunarc_Custom::details.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Sunarc\Custom\ViewModel\Customer</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2:- Create a view model file under Vendor/Module/ViewModel/Customer.php

```
<?php

$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$collection = $viewModel->getCollection();
if ($collection->count()) {
?>
    <div class="table-wrapper customer">
        <table class="data table" id="my-custom-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?php echo __('ID') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col name"><?php echo __('Name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col email"><?php echo __('Email') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($collection as $item) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('ID')) ?>" class="col id">
                            <?php echo $item->getId() ?>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?>" class="col name">
                            <?php echo $item->getName() ?>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?>" class="col email">
                            <?php echo $item->getEmail() ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Step 3:- Create your custom phtml file in Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/details.php

```
<?php

$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$collection = $viewModel->getCollection();
if ($collection->count()) {
?>
    <div class="table-wrapper customer">
        <table class="data table" id="my-custom-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" class="col id"><?php echo __('ID') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col name"><?php echo __('Name') ?></th>
                    <th scope="col" class="col email"><?php echo __('Email') ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                foreach ($collection as $item) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('ID')) ?>" class="col id">
                            <?php echo $item->getId() ?>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?>" class="col name">
                            <?php echo $item->getName() ?>
                        </td>
                        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?>" class="col email">
                            <?php echo $item->getEmail() ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**One can also use Block Files to do the same.**